# How to simply format fields in a python dataframe

Tags: python, formatting, pandas, decimal

I just want to make my print output look a little nicer. at the moment i get this

```
Country Month   RevYear1    RevYear2    RevYear3
1   AT  201311  1168163.992 655483.6382 491612.7286
2   AU  201311  1570301.089 894369.1894 670776.892
3   BE  201311  343942.1705 164049.0644 123036.7983
4   BR  201311  5081321.793 2032528.717 1016264.359
5   CA  201311  1892595.031 841153.347  630865.0102
6   CH  201311  2318145.658 1285991.47  964493.6022
```

how can i format column RevYear1 through RevYear3 change its format to print like 112,456.78 for example.

Answer (score 0):

The string `format()` method [(documentation)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) is your friend here. For instance, assuming that the input data are floats, the command

```
print '{0} {1} {2:,.2f} {3:,.2f} {4:,.2f}'.format('AT','201311',1168163.992,655483.6382,491612.7286)
```

produces

```
AT 201311 1,168,163.99 655,483.64 491,612.73
```

Note that the numbers are rounded to two decimal places (the `.2f` in the format specification), and the comma gives you the thousands separator.

Comment: Thanks. But how do i apply that formatting to a dataframe? like ---print dfTotalv3.format({0} {1} {2:,.2f} {3:,.2f} {4:,.2f}) or how could i just format one column by referencing its field name and the format i want

Comment: @IcemanBerlin I'm not familiar with dataframe. I guess the most natural way is to get the data for the whole row, and format it accordingly. How do you get row data using this dataframe package? For instance, do you get a list of values for each row? If this is the case, the answer should be easy...

Comment: I am also new to python and pandas. I can select the column list of a dataframe by setting  the collist=['GECYEAR1'] and then
print dfTotalv3[collist]. Maybe people working with dataframes dont care about the view. I guess at some point i can manipulate it later once i decide how i want to actually report the output.